# How to select only one item from Listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I have a Listbox widget with multiple entries. I am using the method `select_set(index)` to select items from list but the problem is it is selecting more than one item without deselecting the previous one. I want to select only one item at a time. Since `selectmode` is **'single'** so shouldn't it select only one item? I tried `selection_set(1,1)` but it also doesn't seem to work.

**How can I deselect all other entries and select only one entry?**

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

group_list = tk.Listbox(root, height=10, selectmode='single')
group_list.pack()

group_list.insert(0, "Group 1")
group_list.insert(1, "Group 2") #selects group 2 as well without deselecting group 1

group_list.select_set(0)
group_list.select_set(1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try using `group_list.curselection()` instead of `group_list.select_set`. `curselection` will return a tuple of indices, simple choose the first one.

Comment: @Derek the immediate aim is to select one item using function and not returning the current selection

Answer (score 2):

You can clear a selection by using the method `group_list.select_clear()`

##### Edit:

To clarify:

- To remove a single selection: `.select_clear(index)`
- To remove all selections use: `.select_clear(0, tk.END)`

Comment: `select_clear(start, end)` requires at least one argument. This works fine - `group_list.select_clear(*group_list.curselection())`

Comment: @avm Edited for clarification.